# On the infinitesimals.

Tags: calculus, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I have completed my calculus course a few months back, I was introduced to the idea of infinitesimals as just a symbol in that course. Now I see that they are being used not only in math but in many physics too. I tried to understand the idea of infinitesimals in a intuitive way but found that it requires something called as model theory and non standard analysis. But I know nothing about it.
So I was thinking if there is any proof on the existence of infinitesimals in a simple and intuitive way. And ofcourse I tried to get a proof of my own but I could get nothing.
So I need someone's help to prove the existence of infinitesimals in a elegent and intuitive way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you do not need a proof of existence of infinitesimal. Because it is kind of like proving the existence of numbers. However there is a proof that infinitesimal does not exists in the set of real numbers. This property of real numbers is called the ARCHIMEDEAN PRINCIPLE or the ARCHIMEDEAN PROPERTY OF THE REAL NUMBERS.

Comment: Ranjit Kumar Sarkar

Comment: Can you please provide the proof that infinitesimals does not exist on set of reals.

Comment: It is called non-standard analysis because most modern analysis/calculus is done without the notion of infinitesimals. $\epsilon$-$\delta$ analysis is elegant because it uses similar intuition and more easily justified assumptions.

Comment: I request a proof either on existence of infinitesimals or proof of Archimedes principle

Comment: Daniel Apsley , as I already mentioned in the question I know that non standard analysis is an elegant and satisfying answer but it requires sophisticated model theory like the proof of low theorem whose special case forms the transfer principle. I requested any other alternative for this.

Comment: The archimedean principle states: "Given two positive numbers x and y, there is an integer n so that nx > y."  There is a wikipedia article on the archmedean property:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property. If you read the article you will see that it is written that "Roughly speaking, it is the property of having no infinitely large or infinitely small elements."

Comment: There is a video on youtube which gives a proof of the statement. Let me give you the link of that video:https://youtu.be/UwaecbaAR7g. The video does not seems to be made with much effort but I think the proof given in the video is valid. However I am not sure that how the property of having no infinite large or infinitely small elements is derived from the original statement of the archimedean property.

Comment: I am sorry that I had to wait you for 2 hours.

Comment: Ranjit Kumar Sarkar, thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a question about your question: we do not use infinitesimals directly in calculus, they are implicitly assumed in derivatives, integrals and limits. Then where did you see notations for infinitesimals in a calculus course?.

Comment: Actually I had completed my calculus course 2 years back and work on some areas of physics(like and quantum mechanics and relativity). I was unable to convince the idea of infinitesimals when I heard them as being infinitely small quantities. And I wanted a simple answer so I lied that I just completed my calculus course. Sorry for that.

Comment: If you search the internet for `proof that the reals are archimedean`, you will find many proofs that the real numbers do not contain infinitesimals. If you want to understand what it's like to do Calculus on real numbers using the power of (non-real) infinitesimals, you can read the textbook [Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html). But it sounds like your main question is neither of those and is something like "what's an intuitive construction of infinitesimals?".

Comment: @Rahul, well that explains a lot.

Comment: Mark S, yes you got me right,my question is on the intuitive construction of infinitesimals. Please help me in some way you can.

Comment: @Rahul, you can just define a number $0<\epsilon<r$ where $r$ is a real number. Them $\epsilon$ would be an infinitesimal constructed loosely in an intuitive way.